# SQL Server Convert a nvarchar into a Big Int and back to nvarchar

Tags: t-sql, type-conversion

I have a column on a table that should be a `nvarchar(8)` but was accidentally stored as a `bigint (8 bytes)`. The data is now live.
I need to convert the `bigint` numeric value into the intended `nvarchar(8)` character string.
for example the column value should be 'MOLASSES' but is actually numeric value `5570755107535144275`.

Can anybody help please?

Comment: you cant fit 5570755107535144275 into an nvarchar field of 8 characters

Comment: I Agree with Takarii, moreover any articular reason you want to convert the column from an optimized searchable datatype to a string. are you expecting Unicode data?

Comment: I am frequently intrigued when potential help is preceded by questions such as "Why do you want to do this?" etc. Its as though the offer of help will be dependant on the reason for for the requirement.

Comment: The data is supplied as a stream of bytes. This particular data item is intended to be interpreted as an 8 character string. The reason for nvachar rather than varchar is simply because the resultant data will be read via any number of syste4ms.

Comment: It is not an option to change the data format of the nvarchar target - as stated the resultant data is live.

Comment: What does your code that's inserting into this table look like? I'm not understanding how a string like 'MOLASSES' would even get converted to bigint. Both implicit and explicit conversion fail.

Comment: Hi . Thanks for your interest. The data was received in a stream of bytes and due to a coding error in a .Net application was converted to a 64 bit integer and written to SQL Server. It should have been converted to a 8 byte nvarchar instead. The coding error was mine and  is now fixed. I just need to convert the existing data.

Comment: @user3049876 The main reason people ask why someone wants to do something is because very often the question being asked is the wrong way to go about solving a particular problem. In this case, the problem itself looks like a mistake until I read your final comment which made the solution obvious to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a bigint back to a varchar, convert it back to the binary value first.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3e91f/2

```
CREATE TABLE BYTESTREAM(VALUE BIGINT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO BYTESTREAM VALUES (5570755107535144275);

SELECT VALUE
, CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), VALUE)
, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), VALUE))
FROM BYTESTREAM
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I look at the solution now and agree it is obvious.